# How to prevent windows from being translucent when switching with alt-tab in KDE?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, kde, window-manager

I'm using KDE dektop and a 'compact' task switcher.

When I'm cycling through the windows to choose which to switch to with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>), all windows apart from the selected one become translucent and the selected window raises to the top. I personally find this very distracting.

Is there any way to turn this off? I want <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to only show the task switcher window and do nothing to the application windows until I release <kbd>Alt</kbd> to confirm and switch (similar to how it works in gnome3/cinnamon).

Edit: I see this issue with Ubuntu 18.04.5, KWin 5.12.9 and also Debian testing with KWin 5.17.5. However I also recall seeing similar behaviour on older Ubuntu/KDE versions as well.

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: @Pilot6, Ubuntu 18.04.5, KWin 5.12.9. However I see the same issue on debian testing with KWin 5.17.5, and recall seeing similar behaviour on older ubuntu versions, so I would be surprised if it is distribution-specific.

Comment: You could disable the compositor to disable transparency completely

Comment: @MaxSilvester I don't want to disable the compositor, with modern appplication expectations it does significantly more harm. I want to get rid of only one specific effect.

Comment: @MaxSilvester additionally, disabling the compositor removes the transparency effect, but not the 'raise to the top' part, which is sufficiently distracting in the absence of compositor as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was found elsewhere:

Open System Settings->Window management->Task switcher (or run `kcmshell5 kwintabbox`), uncheck "show selected window".